# How do I find the mean and standard deviation of a table?

Tags: statistics

I'm not sure I understand how this example arrived at $\frac{3}{2}$, $2$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\sqrt\frac{1}{2}$ given in the information in the table. Can someone show me exactly which number did they use and the calculation in this example? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: The are saying that $x$ takes the values $1$ and $2$ with equal probability and $y$ takes the values $1,2,\text{ and }3$ with equal probability.

Comment: I get what you mean, but I don't get where is the 3/2 coming from? How did they get 3/2...?

Comment: $\frac32={1+2\over2}, 2={1+2+3\over3}$

Comment: Oh, and how about the standard deviation part for y? Can you explain where sqrt 1/2 is gotten from?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the variance? The standard deviation is the square root of the variance.

Comment: Yes, but why is it over 2 and not n = 3? Is it because it is divided by n-1 and not only n?

Comment: Why is *what* over $2$ and not $3$?  Please add the details to the body of your question, by editing the question, not as a comment.

Comment: The table muddies the waters, since the only distributions of used are for $x$ and $y$ alone.  The joint distribution is not used.